# Pusher not working in php

Tags: php, xampp, pusher

I am trying to integrate Pusher with php using 'pusher php server'. I am using xamp server. I tried with the examples but is not working. If I run the below code.

```
require('vendor\pusher\pusher-php-server\lib\Pusher.php'); 
$app_id = '216511'; 
$app_key = '40403e9b91d636322403';
$app_secret = '255060847263ef97c5d8';

class MyLogger {
  public function log( $msg ) {
    print_r( $msg . "<br />" );
  }
}

$pusher = new Pusher($app_key, $app_secret, $app_id);
$logger = new MyLogger();
$pusher->set_logger( $logger );

$data['message'] = 'hello world';
$result = $pusher->trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', $data);
$logger->log( "---- My Result ---" );
$logger->log( $result );
```

I am getting the message

```
Pusher: trigger POST: {"name":"my_event","data":"{\"message\":\"hello world\"}","channels":["test_channel"]}
Pusher: exec_curl response: Array ( [body] => Timestamp expired: Given timestamp (2016-06-17T06:26:35Z) not within 600s of server time (2016-06-16T06:26:55Z) [status] => 401 )
```

Please help.