# PHP Pusher Event Triggering not working

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, pusher

I am a newbie when it comes to WebSockets, and I recently came across [Pusher](https://www.pusher.com/). I wanted to integrate it in my website. I am trying to trigger an event via the Pusher.php file, and here is my code:

```
$pusherArray['success'] = true;
        $pusher = new Pusher( $PUSHER_APP_KEY, $PUSHER_APP_SECRET, $PUSHER_APP_ID );
        class MyLogger {
          public function log( $msg ) {
            print_r( $msg . "\n" );
          }
        }

        $pusher->set_logger( new MyLogger() );
        $pusher->trigger('8307851079', 'logout', $pusherArray);
        $info = $pusher->get_channel_info("$clef_id");
        $channel_occupied = $info->occupied;
        var_dump($channel_occupied);
```

And then this is the result I get:

```
Pusher: curl_init( http://api.pusherapp.com:80/apps/217851/events?auth_key=MY_KEY&auth_signature=SIGNATURE&auth_timestamp=1466342695&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=41b74623d1e5f479b466093805ff36de )
Pusher: trigger POST: {"name":"logout","data":"{\"success\":true}","channels":8307851079}
Pusher: exec_curl response: Array
(
    [body] => Expected channels parameter to be an array

    [status] => 400
)

Pusher: curl_init( http://api.pusherapp.com:80/apps/217851/channels/8307851079?auth_key=MY_KEY&auth_signature=SIGNATURE&auth_timestamp=1466342696&auth_version=1.0 )
Pusher: exec_curl response: Array
(
    [body] => 404 NOT FOUND

    [status] => 404
)

NULL
```

The event is not getting triggered! Need some help!

Comment: Did you check the [phpdoc](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php/blob/master/lib/Pusher.php#L402)? The first argument given to the trigger method should be an array. You are passing a string.

Comment: @RobApodace isn't that for `$info = $pusher->get_channel_info("$clef_id");` but the trigger itself is not working!

Comment: @RobApodaca I tried that out and the trigger returned status code 200! But I still got the 404 Not found error after that! And I still can't see my event on the Pusher Debug Console Log.. Whereas all the connections and channels are shown!

Comment: I provided an answer to this a few days ago, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851532/pusher-not-working-in-php/37861981#37861981.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working! Is there a way I can close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work eventually. What had happened was that the view channel info method was causing the error. I did not have proper syntax.

And as pointed out by [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907876/php-pusher-event-triggering-not-working#comment63269698_37907876), the first argument of the trigger function required it to be an array. I changed that and got the script to work. Here's the brief code:

```
    $pusherArray['success'] = true; 
$pusher = new Pusher( $PUSHER_APP_KEY, $PUSHER_APP_SECRET, $PUSHER_APP_ID );
class MyLogger { public function log( $msg ) { print_r( $msg . "\n" ); } } 
$pusher->set_logger( new MyLogger() ); 
$pusher->trigger(['8307851079'], 'logout', $pusherArray);
```

I just simply removed the view channel info because I didn't really need that function. Got a 200 OK status code and my script was able to deliver the

> "success":true

Message to the Pusher service.